# Select query with a number range in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a user table like this:

```
User (id, name, rank)
```

I want to check user's rank and get the corresponding text (ex: if user's rank in between 1-10, I can get the text "User in top 10!")

I created a rank_text table like this:

```
rank_text(id, rank_from, rank_to, text)
         (1,  1,         10,      "You are in top 10!")
```

How I can query this case?

Can you give me a advise?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `join`:

```
select u.*, rt.text
from users u left join
     rank_text rt
     on u.rank between rt.rank_from and rt.rank_to;
```